# Update Cookie via HTML select element

Tags: php, html

I want to built a "currency-changer" for a website. Right now, I am setting a cookie via PHP. The name is "Currency", the value is "USD".

So if a user enters the site, this cookie is set.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['Currency'])) {
   setcookie('Currency', 'USD' ,time()+31536000, '/', '.domain.com');
   $_COOKIE['Currency'] = 'USD';
}
```

What I now want to achieve is, that the cookie can be updated via an HTLM select-list.

```
<form>
  <select id="setcurrency" name="setcurrency" />
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</form>
```

How could I do it the best way, so that the cookie is updated and then the page is reloaded. All this needs to be done in PHP. I could do it in JQuery, but PHP is a must and I am a noob :(

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: on select change event, use ajax and on success reload on js side. what's the big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery with PHP then you can try this:

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#setcurrency").change(function(){
       $("#formID").submit(); // you need to add form id and form method
    });
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['setcurrency'])) {
   setcookie('Currency', $_POST['setcurrency'] ,time()+31536000, '/', '.domain.com');   
}
```

in `jQuery`, first of all you need to add `id="formID"` on your form with `method="post"` and make sure `jQuery` library included in your code.

In my `jQuery` example, i am just submitting the form on dropdown selection.

Then you can overwrite the existing cookie value by using `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

How about having an iframe with a blank html file, with the iframe having a name, and the form targets the iframe with a post/get action to a php file and then in that php file you update the cookie?

Of course, then the parent page that is posting/getting the form data will need a refresh or reload to read that cookie